# Problem getting size of Website Xcode

Tags: xcode, integer, nsdata

When i try and compile I come up with a warning that reads initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast.  No clue why.  I am just trying to get the size of a website.

```
#import "Lockerz_RedemptionViewController.h"

@implementation Lockerz_RedemptionViewController

-(IBAction)startLoop:(id) sender {
    NSData *dataNew = [NSData dataWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
            URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]]; 

    NSUInteger *len = [dataNew length];  //error is here

    NSLog(@"%@", len);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUInteger is just a wrapper for an unsigned int, alter your code to this (i.e. remove the * as it's not a pointer to an object)

```
NSUInteger len = [dataNew length];
```

Also I think you're going a bit overboard with your initialisation, why not just do

```
NSData *dataNew = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
                   URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
```

That should return you an autoreleased object containing the data you need